# How to keep track of the sort index with Knockout-sortable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using [Knockout-sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) to drag-and-drop/sort records in my table, but I've run into a problem. I have no clue how to keep track of the position in the sort index of an element. (I.e. element A, B and C appear in that order and have 1,2,3 as index respectively, but if B gets dropped above A the correct index would be 2,1,3)

Nothing in my code is custom: I just include knockout-sortable and it's plug and play. I usually always include a code snippet, but I don't feel that's useful. The only thing I know is that I'm probably gonna need a `ko.computed()`, but I have no idea what to fill it in with.

Comment: If you need a nice property on your objects that holds the index, then take a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836810/knockout-sortable-bind-order.  By using the `indexed` extensions created in the answer, your items will automatically keep their index up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at example http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Jr2rE/, you can see that the plug-in works by updating an observable array of data.  Because of this, you don't have to keep track of the index value. The order of the records, technically, gives you all the information you need.

That being said, I ran into the same issue in last year.  To solve my problem, I added a consecutively numbered index property to each object in my observable array.  Then, when the sortable plug-in re-arranged the contents of the observable array, I just had to read out the new index property to know the sort order.